# Escape comma (,) in file path for sublime find in files option

Tags: editor, sublimetext, nautilus

As the title says, I have a file path which is having comma in it. For e.g `/home/jimy/projects/try,outs`
When I do find in files with this path it only takes till comma i.e. `/home/jimy/projects/try`. So how to escape the comma in it?

Comment: Have you tried a backslash ``\`` to escape the comma?

Comment: @Zeeker yes but then the path becomes `/home/jimy/projects/try\\`

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if I understand your problem completly, where exactly lies the issue? You can not find the file?

Comment: @Zeeker I am not able to find in file. as the path break at space. And the wrost part is, it is a shared folder on network drive and can't change it :(

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm sorry but I have no idea how to fix that. Maybe write an issue on the [github issue page of ST](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues) or create a topic in their [forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3). Good luck!

Comment: What about using wildcard `?` instead of the comma character?